# How to store an image file after uploading the image file in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I am fairly new to Coldfusion and I am having a hard time to figure out how to allow users to upload images in my form

Currently, I was able to find the following code that will upload the image in Coldfusion:

```
<cfparam name="form.fileUpload" default="">
​
<cfif len(trim(form.fileUpload))>
  <cffile action="upload"
     fileField="fileUpload"
     destination="C:\docs">
  <p>Thankyou, your file has been uploaded.</p>
</cfif>
​
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Although it gives me an idea on how to approach my issue, I still not sure on the following:

Instead of the `destination="C:\docs"` storing the file at a drive, I would like to be able to upload the uploaded image to an email. The reason being is the once the user finishes and submits the form, an email will be sent out to the user who submitted the request and the user who will be assigned in creating the card.

How can I achieve this? Any suggestions and examples would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to attach the uploaded image to an email?

Comment: I think the uploaded data is streamed and thus needs a destination to write to. You can use [in-memory disk](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-70e2363b121825b20e7-8000.html) if you want the data to be volatile. But why exactly do you need a variable?

Comment: @Alex: I dont need one but I was uncertain how to approach it and that is why I said variable.

Comment: @AlexBaban: Yes, I am trying to uploaded image to an email. I currently have another cfm file that sends out the email but formats the info. Meaning it will display in a certain way in the email

Comment: @RobertoFlores [Check this out.](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/834-ask-ben-upload-and-email-file-using-coldfusion.htm) This looks like your scenario.

Comment: I would also strongly caution against allowing an unchecked file to be saved to a drive on your server, even if it's just temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CFMAILPARAM` with `remove="yes"`. You can also show the filename in the email. Full example:

```
<cfmail
    to="the@recipient.com"
    subject="#application.companyName# Contact Submission"
    type="html"
    from="#form.email#">

    <!--- WAS A FILE UPLOADED? --->
    <cfif isDefined("form.attachment") and form.attachment neq ''>
        <!--- SAVE THE FILE --->
        <cffile action="upload" fileField="attachment" destination="#expandPath('./')#" nameConflict="Overwrite">
        <!--- ATTACH TO EMAIL, THEN DELETE IT --->
        <cfmailparam
            disposition = "attachment"
            file = "#expandPath('./' & cffile.serverfile)#"
            remove = 'yes'>
        <!--- MAKE THE FILE NAME A FORM FIELD --->
        <cfset form.attachment = cffile.serverfile>
    </cfif>

    <html>
    <body>
        <cfset form.URL = cgi.http_referrer>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
            <tr>
                <th>Field</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
            <cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="f">
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap="nowrap" valign="top">#replace(f, '_', ' ', 'all')#</td>
                    <td>#form[f]#</td>
                </tr>
            </cfloop>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
</cfmail>
```